# Not able to integrate Jvisual Vm with Jboss EAP 6.1

Tags: jboss, jvisualvm

I am not able to integrate JVisualVM with jboss EAP 6.1. Below are steps i done:
    Edited the startup file and added the below params in that-
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3614 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

```
But i am getting below error:

Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
Could not load Logmanager "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$1.run(LogManager.java:191)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:181)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:339)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:393)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLogger.<init>(ClassLogger.java:55)
        at sun.management.jmxremote.ConnectorBootstrap.<clinit>(ConnectorBootstrap.java:830)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:260)
        at sun.management.Agent.startAgent(Agent.java:456)
WARNING: Failed to load the specified log manager class org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
Aug 17, 2017 5:46:51 AM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
Aug 17, 2017 5:46:51 AM org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService start
INFO: JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA (AS 7.2.0.Final-redhat-8) starting
Aug 17, 2017 5:46:52 AM org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext executeStep
ERROR: JBAS014612: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([])
java.lang.RuntimeException: JBAS014670: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:99)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:440)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:322)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:229)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:224)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:232)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:333)
        at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:308)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:188)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:91)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBAS011592: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
        at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingExtension.initialize(LoggingExtension.java:103)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:97)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127)
        at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:113)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)

Aug 17, 2017 5:46:52 AM org.jboss.as.server.ServerService boot
FATAL: JBAS015957: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.



Thanks & Regards,
Rishabh Jain
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect with JVisualVM to JBoss, you need to add the `jboss-cli-client.jar` to the classpath:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jvisualvm -cp:a $JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-cli-client.jar
```

If this jar is not available in your EAP version, then you must add the following modules under `$JBOSS_HOME/modules` to the classpath:

```
org/jboss/remoting3/remoting-jmx org/jboss/remoting3 org/jboss/logging org/jboss/xnio org/jboss/xnio/nio org/jboss/sasl org/jboss/marshalling org/jboss/marshalling/river org/jboss/as/cli org/jboss/staxmapper org/jboss/as/protocol org/jboss/dmr org/jboss/as/controller-client org/jboss/threads org/jboss/as/controller
```

[This](http://org/jboss/remoting3/remoting-jmx%20org/jboss/remoting3%20org/jboss/logging%20org/jboss/xnio%20org/jboss/xnio/nio%20org/jboss/sasl%20org/jboss/marshalling%20org/jboss/marshalling/river%20org/jboss/as/cli%20org/jboss/staxmapper%20org/jboss/as/protocol%20org/jboss/dmr%20org/jboss/as/controller-client%20org/jboss/threads%20org/jboss/as/controller) blog post has a script that you can be used for that. If you are registered customer, you can also download a script [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/151343).